# Heroku + Rails + Angular [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, heroku

I'm having a problem with an angular.js/rails application, working locally, that results in a js crash on Heroku.

To allow for local testing, I downloaded and placed all angular.js files in the vendor directory. I'm not using any gems, simply placing the angular files in the asset pipeline so that the individual controller coffeescript files can use the angular library.

This is my app.js:

```
angular.module('generosity', ['ngRoute', 'templates'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: "users-form.html",
                controller: 'UsersController'
            }).
            // when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        //      templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        //      controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
            // }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }])

.controller('UsersController' ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    var self = this;

    self.username;
    self.realName;
    self.password;
    self.availableHours; //How should this be styled?
    self.currentCity;
    self.currentLocation;
    self.recipient; //Should probably be renamed


    $scope.errCode = 0;

    self.addUser = function() {
        var errCode;
        $http.post('users/add', {username: self.username, password: self.password}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
                var errCode = data.errCode;
                self.retrieveErrCode(errCode);
                // console.log("HYA" + self.errCode);
                if(errCode == -2) {
                    alert("Error: This username already exists.");
                }
                else if(errCode == -3) {
                    alert("Error: The username is empty, too long, or has invalid characters.");
                }
                else if(errCode == -4) {
                    alert("Error: The password is empty, too long, or has invalid characters.");
                }
                else {
                    alert("User created.");                     
                }
                console.log(errCode);
                $rootScope.errCode = data.errCode;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
                alert("Error.");
            });
            console.log(self.username);
        return $scope.errCode;
    }

    self.retrieveErrCode = function(code) {
        $scope.err = code;
        console.log("here");
    };

    self.createDummyUser = function() {
        self.username = "LordChristopher";
        self.realName = "Lord Christopher";
        self.password = "Team 61C";
        self.availableHours = "6 to 11 pm";
        self.currentCity = "Berkeley";
        self.currentLocation = "Nowhere";
        self.recipient = "He whose name shall not be spoken";
    };

    // self.login = function(name, pw) {

    // };

    // self.logout = function() {

    // };
}])

.controller('SessionController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    var self = this;

    self.userId;
    self.username;

    self.login = function(username, password) {
        $http.post('login', {username: username, password: password}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
                alert("Connected");
                console.log("connected");
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
                console.log("error");
                alert("Error.");
            });
    }
}])

.directive('navbar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "navbar.html"
    };
})

.directive('usersForm', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {

        },
        templateUrl: "users-form.html"
    };
})

.directive('loginForm', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {

        },
        templateUrl: "login-form.html"
    };
})  

.directive('usersTests', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {

        },
        templateUrl: "users-tests.html"
    };
})

// .directive('directiveA', function() {
//  return {
//      restrict: 'A',
//      scope: {
//          name: '@',
//          hobby: '@'
//      },
//      templateUrl: "example-module.html"
//  };
// }) //Only put a semi-colon on the last directory of the module

.directive('css1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.css("width", 400),
            element.css("font-style", "oblique");
            element.css("color", "green");
            element.css("font-size", "30px");
        }
    };
})

.directive('testStatus', function() { //You do not need to account for the cases for which the rating is not a number.
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
          message: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { //Note that this is a function of scope, NOT $scope!!
            if(scope.message.search("PASS") > 0) {
                element.css("color", "green");
            }
            else if(scope.message.search("FAIL") > 0) {
                element.css("color", "red");
            }
            else {
                element.css("color", "blue");
            }
        }
    };
})
```

It runs just fine locally, using Rails s. However, despite my best efforts (all the "serve static assets:true" in config/assets/production.rb, and several add-on gems that auto-minify js files for production) heroku returns the following stacktrace:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module generosity due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'generosity' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/nomod?p0=generosity
    at https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:5:20793
    at https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:5:28971
    at e (https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:5:28543)
    at https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:5:28855
    at https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:6:4062
    at o (https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:5:21178)
    at h (https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:6:3840)
    at _e (https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:6:5485)
    at Q.s (https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:5:26814)
    at Q (https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:5:27124)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=generosity&p1=Error…com%2Fassets%2Fapplication-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js%3A5%3A27124) application-b623e3dc11cb731dd5e417203ceb10d1.js:6
```

For clarity, "generosity" is the name of the app itself, which was defined in app.js.

Why would the module I defined be impossible to find in production, and not in local?

The app can be found at https://still-plains-1604.herokuapp.com/ literally any help with this issue would be a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

Your source has a couple issues.

1. The HTML has two `data-ng-app` tags.
2. The angular-route file, which seems necessary for the app, isn't there.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! These are actually lingering "fix" attempts from other stackoverflow questions. I was afraid angular-route.js wasn't importing correctly so I tried to set it as a manual <script> tag--however it is being imported just fine as an asset in the rails pipeline.

I updated the heroku site to reflect this--removing these two issues still hasn't solved the problem of blank display...